# Cannot precompile all files (app\assets) in rails application though rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a rails application and try to Run it to my local server on Win2012 now right.

https://github.com/carloscoca/loccasions

I tried to precompile all Files in app\assets though the command rake assets:precompile and no errors came out.

However, I ran the website though localhost, but look incomplete it need some files and I checked the log file. (Some files was precompile a others not, in the manifest file is the same).

I tried config.assets.compile = true, not result and some configuration too, no luck

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/layout.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/layout.css"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/default.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400
Served asset /default.css - 404 Not Found (2ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.css"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/default.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400
Served asset /default.js - 404 Not Found (0ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/default.js"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/skeleton.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/skeleton.css"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)


Started GET "/stylesheets/base.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/base.css"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.0ms)


Started GET "/javascripts/tabs.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-07 10:28:45 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/tabs.js"):


Rendered C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Comment: I usually compile with a specific environnement: bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production I don't why but with just rake assets:precompile I have issues (long time ago)

Comment: I assume you try running in production on your localhost? In your config/environnement/production.rb check if config.serve_static_files = true (I think it is false by default because your production server will usually serve static files).

Comment: rake assets:precompile
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development --trace
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production --trace

I Try in production, Development, config envorionment with config.serve_static_files = true
Command rake works with some files in app\assets, i don't know why some files and not all

Comment: In your config/application.rb you may need to add the specific files in this line: config.assets.precompile += %w(base.*, skeleton.* .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, this answer belongs to "coded addicted"

**In your config/application.rb you may need to add the specific files in this line: config.assets.precompile += %w(base.*, skeleton.* .....)**